# SQL Join On Columns of Different Length

Tags: sql, database, join, sas

I'm trying to join two tables together in SQL where the columns contain a different number of unique entries.

When I use a full join the additional entries in the column joined on are missing.

The code I'm using is (in a SAS proc SQL):

```
proc sql;
create table table3 as
select table1.*, table2.*
from table1 full join table2
on table1.id = table2.id;
quit;
```

Visual example of problem (can't show actual tables as contain sensitive data)

```
Table 1
  id  | count1
  1   |   2
  2   |   3
  3   |   2

Table 2
 id   | count2
  1   |   4
  2   |   5
  3   |   6
  4   |   2

Table 3
 id   | counta | countb
  1   |   2    |   4
  2   |   3    |   5
  3   |   2    |   6
  -   |   -    |   2     <----- I want don't want the id column to be blank in this row
```

I hope I've explained my problem clearly enough, thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Simply select `coalesce(t1.id, t2.id)`, will return the first non-null id value.

Comment: Side note that the query you posted there will not produce the table 3 you’ve posted- it will produce 4 columns and you posted 3

Comment: @CaiusJard  In SAS you cannot have two variables with the same name. So if you save that query to a dataset just the first column named `ID` will saved and the other copy will be ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The id from table 1 is blank because the row from table2 has no match in table 1. Try looking at the output from this query:

```
select coalesce(table1.id, table2.id) as id, table1.count1, table2.count2
from table1 full join table2
on table1.id = table2.id;
```

Coalesce works from left to right returning the first non null value (it can take more than 2 arguments). If the id in table 1 is null it uses the id from table 2 instead

I recommend also to alias all tables in queries, so I’d have written this:

```
SELECT 
  COALESCE(t1.id, t2.id) as id, 
  t1.count1, 
  t2.count2
FROM 
  table1 t1 
  FULL OUTER JOIN 
  table2 t2
  ON 
    t1.id = t2.id;
```

Comment: That works, thank you very much. 
Could you explain a little how it works please?

Answer (score 0):

Simply select `coalesce(t1.id, t2.id)`, will return the first non-null id value.